# How to use HTML spacing in email body Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, html-email

I am sending email from google sheet data via google apps script. But the problem is the spacing is not correctly formatted

I have tried using "  " but the spacing remains the same. How to make spacing in email body?

```
 for (var m=0;m<resultArr.length;m++) {
        body+= "For Part No "+resultArr[m][0].toString()+" " +"  Month   "  
 +resultArr[m][1].toString()+",Quantity is "+resultArr[m][2].toString()+" 
<br>";

      }
```

I want to move the "Month" and "Quantity" to the right so that it will align correctly in email body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, html spaces are collapsed. You can set [white-space](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) to `pre` or `pre-wrap` to preserve spaces.

```
var body = "<body style='white-space:pre-wrap'>";
 for (var m=0;m<resultArr.length;m++) {
        body+= "For Part No "+resultArr[m][0].toString()+" " +"  Month   "+resultArr[m][1].toString()+",Quantity is "+resultArr[m][2].toString()+" <br>";
}
body += "</body>"
```

Comment: `pre` or `pre-wrap` will not work properly in some email clients like Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

Try this loop:

```
for (var m=0;m<resultArr.length;m++) {
        body+= "<td style='font-family:Arial; font-size:15px;'>For Part No "+resultArr[m][0].toString()+" " +"</td><td>  Month   " +resultArr[m][1].toString()+"</td><td>Quantity is "+resultArr[m][2].toString()+"</td>";
}
```

add this table around the loop

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
        <!-- loop goes here -->
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The loop will create 3 columns while the rest of the code will create the code necessary for a table to hold.

Comment: Sorry didnt realise i had placed double quotes inside double quotes. Also the chosen answer will work but not render same across all email clients. With my code you just need a web safe font family and a font size to render same across all email clients

Comment: I am getting syntax error at +resultArr[m][1].toString()+"</td><td>Quantity is "+resultArr[m][2].toString()+"</td>";

Comment: Try removing the line break before it and see if it works?

Comment: Line break removed in the example, let me know if it works for you now.