# How to align email body in google apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, html-email

I'm facing issue in aligning the data from google sheets when sending it in email body.

So far, its spacing out according to the part numbers. I want "months" and "quantity" in a straight column.

```
var body = "<body style='white-space:pre-wrap'>";
for (var m=0;m<resultArr.length;m++)
     {
        body+= "For Part No  "+resultArr[m][0].toString()+ "" + "                 
      " +"Month "+resultArr[m][1].toString()+"   Quantity is 
      "+resultArr[m][2].toString()+" <br>";

      }
     body += "</body>"
```

I expect the month and column in one straight line

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use HTML spacing in email body Google Apps Script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56746063/how-to-use-html-spacing-in-email-body-google-apps-script)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, for example, how about using table? Please think of this as just one of several answers.

#### Modified script:

```
body += "<table style=\"border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 20px 0px;\">"
for (var m=0;m<resultArr.length;m++) {
  body+= "<tr><td>For Part No  "+resultArr[m][0].toString()+ "</td><td align=\"right\">Month "+resultArr[m][1].toString()+"</td><td align=\"right\">Quantity is "+resultArr[m][2].toString()+"</td></tr>";
}
body += "</table>";
```

- In this modified script, the table is created without the borders and with the margin between columns of 20 px.

#### References:

- [border-collapse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-collapse)
- [border-spacing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-spacing)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: @Sriram Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.